# HAProxy Email Alert - How to configure password for SMTP?

Tags: smtp, haproxy, high-availability

HAProxy has configuration options to setup email notifications in case of errors. Unfortunately I cannot find a way to configure the email account password for the SMTP connection. Does anyone know how this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

This feature isn't implemented yet http://git.haproxy.org/?p=haproxy.git;a=blob;f=src/mailers.c;h=3df02f0f55759b8340fbbea676dde62e9260e7df;hb=HEAD

Patches are welcome to add this feature.